# Bluenrg-ms/stm32F4 : Hci packet through spi

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, bluenrg

I am working on a project to developp a ble communication but i'm having some trouble to initialize and comprehend the return frame from ble.

After lowering the cs, testing the header (0x0A,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00) and sending directly after hci_reset (0x01,0x03,0x0C,0x00) with HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive, I want to read the return value from ble.

So lowering the cs one more time, test header (0x0B,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00) and sending dummies data with HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive.
I obtain this frame : 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00.

But from what I have understood this far I should obtain something like :0x04,0x0E,0x04,0x01,0x03,0x0C,0x00.

Can someone point out where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Almost resolved.

Actually I changed some points in my code and finally retrieved the data from ble corresponding to what I was waiting for.

What I was doing before was closing the frame after receiving right header from ble. Then sending header to write command followed by **the** command.

That is the procedure I applied :
Information communication spi (write):
• open CS
◦ send header_master[5]={0x0a,0,0,0,0} in TransmitReceive
▪ if header_slave[0]=0x02 and header_slave[1]>0
• send commands
• close CS
▪ else
• close CS
• goto open CS

Information communication spi (read):
• wait for exti from ble
◦ Open CS
▪ send header_master[5]={0x0b,0,0,0,0} in TransmitReceive
• if header_slave[0]=0x02 and header_slave[3]>0
◦ send (header_slave[3]) dummies
◦ close CS
• else
◦ close CS
◦ goto open CS

Hope that can help some people.

Now i'm facing an other issue. I don't receive the interrupt after sending the command so I do polling up to catching the frame I need. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You must always start to reset the bluenrg first: this will cause the bluenrg to trigger an interrupt. It is unclear what the behaviour is without the hard reset.